# get name values basing on a value of another attribute in the block

Tags: json, jq

with jq, I'd like to get "name" value of blocks where "Media" attribute (under .session.attributeList) contains "node7000" string (in example json first array block matches it - there are two matching:

"value": "node7000"

"value": "node7000 and node8000"

and expected jq output would be:

"Station 17200"

```
[{
    "name": "Station 17200",
    "attributes": [{
            "name": "EnableLog",
            "value": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "LogFont",
            "value": "0"
        }, {
            "name": "IdleTimer",
            "value": "30"
        }
    ],
    "session": [{
            "attributeList": [{
                    "name": "Launch",
                    "value": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "Media",
                    "value": "node7000"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "attributeList": [{
                    "name": "Group",
                    "value": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "RMedia",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "attributeList": [{
                    "name": "Launch",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Media",
                    "value": "node7000 and node8000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Station 17300",
    "attributes": [{
            "name": "EnableLog",
            "value": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "LogFont",
            "value": "0"
        }, {
            "name": "IdleTimer",
            "value": "30"
        }
    ],
    "session": [{
            "attributeList": [{
                    "name": "Launch",
                    "value": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "Media",
                    "value": "node6000"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "attributeList": [{
                    "name": "Group",
                    "value": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "RMedia",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "attributeList": [{
                    "name": "Launch",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Media",
                    "value": "node6001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 7):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq '.[] | select([.session[].attributeList[] 
                   | .name == "Media" and (.value | contains("node7000"))
                 ] | any ).name' jsonfile
```

- `.[]` - iterating over all elements(objects) of the input array
- `select(<condition>)` - the function produces its input unchanged if `<condition>` returns `true` for that input, and produces no output otherwise
- `contains(element)` - the filter produces `true` if `element` is completely contained within the input
- `any` - the filter takes as input an array of boolean values and produces `true` as output if any of the elements of the array are `true`

---

The output:

```
"Station 17200"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show how to rewrite [the `jq` expression that RomanPerekhrest came up with](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417509/116858) so that [the `any(generator; condition)` form of the `any` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)) is used:

```
.[] |
select(
        any(
                .session[].attributeList[];
                .name == "Media" and (.value | contains("node7000"))
        )
).name
```

This instructs the `any` function to extract all `.session[].attributeList[]` values from each element of the top-level array.  It will then create an array of booleans from these `attributeList` elements using the given conditional expression on each of them.  If any of the boolean values are *true*, then that element of the top-level array is selected.  The `name` key's value is then extracted and printed.

Obviously, if you want to make the query string `node7000` depend on e.g. a shell variable, then you'll use `--arg` to pass that into the expression:

```bash
query_string=node7000
jq --arg media "$query_string" '.[] | select(any(.session[].attributeList[]; .name == "Media" and (.value | contains($media)))).name' file.json
```

Change `contains($media)` into `test($media)` if you want to pass a PCRE regular expression rather than a string. This would additionally allow us to specifically look for e.g. `node7000` using word-boundary symbols (`\b`), to avoid risking false positive substring matches with strings like `node70001`:

```bash
jq --arg media '\bnode7000\b' '.[] | select(any(.session[].attributeList[]; .name == "Media" and (.value | test($media)))).name' file.json
```